# Time Series detrending with multiple polynomials

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I'm currently working on energy demand forecasting using daily load data. I'm using data since 1990 and, in order to use ARIMAX models, I detrended the data (using a first-order polynomial) and then I removed seasonality. As we can see on this image [image: monthly load data],

in the last two years there is (unfortunately) a different trend with respect the previous 15 years. I was thinking to use two different first-order polynomials to perform detrend: one fitted on the data 1990-2008 and another one for 2008-2010. What is the best way to do this? I'm not sure if I must use a spline or not. Can you suggest me the best-practice method to perform this kind of detrending?

Thank you, 
P.S. I'm a computer scientist and I'm using R (and MATLAB).

**UPDATE**

This is the loess smothing with span 0.9 [image: LOESS span 0.9]

With span 0.5 [image: LOESS span 0.5]

and finally with span 0.1[image: LOESS span 0.1]

I will try to perform detrending with span 0.5.

** UPDATE [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRMMu.jpg) **
This is the comparison with the time-series with the original detrend (top, a single first-order polynomial) and loess with span 0.5 (bottom). There is an important difference in the last years.

[image: comparison between simple detrend and loess]

Comment: I agree that 0.5 looks smooth and yet shows a reasonable trend. It feels un-statistical to talk about "looks", but I don't know enough to go beyond that. What does the detrended data (i.e. residual after subtracting your loess trend) look like?

Comment: I compared the detrended data obtained both with loess and with a first-order polynomial. The biggest difference shows obviously in the final part, and in fact all the analysis about energy demand is more consistent with our initial hypothesis. I will post a couple of additional figures later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use smoothing with moving average(yearly,12 if the data points are monthly) as a trend estimate. Spline is also a good choice.

Comment: Agreed. If you want to try a spline, perhaps `loess` with `span=0.9` or something like that would be worth it. I really don't think the two-polynomial approach would work: among other things it doesn't look (eyeballing it) like 2008 is the turning point.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an old post on electrical loads:

[Predicting daily electricity load - fitting time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6513/predicting-daily-electricity-load-fitting-time-series/6539#6539)

The underlying long-term (> 5 years) trend is due to economic activity.  As you can see in the graph labeled "US - Total Electricity Demand (Millions of Megawatt-hours)", the blue line is related to U.S. Gross Domestic Product.    Keep in mind that this GDP relationship probably isn't linear.   Here's a link to some GDP data (below is a graph from 1990 to now):

http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/graph/?id=GDP

The seasonal/repeating terms in the load data are winter, spring, summer, fall, holidays, weekdays/weekends, and time-of-day.   For example, a Saturday's (weekend) demand may be lower than a nearby Thursday's demand (for the same temperature/weather), but that weekend/weekday relationship is probably much different in winter versus summer.

The bottom line is, each area has its own peculiarities and requires a lot of tweaking.  If you're at a state level or below, finding a related "GDP" or economic activity data series may be difficult.   From your graph, a 30MW load implies a single industrial plant or a group of small plants.   Your "economic activity data" may be the production level of the plant(s).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check out "[Complimentary Ensemble Empirical Mode Decomposition](http://www.worldscinet.com/aada/02/0202/S1793536910000422.html)" (CEEMD). It's rather compute-intensive, but provides a nicely adaptive approach to characterizing trends across multiple time scales. The original EMD method was published by Huang et al in *Proc Royal Soc A* back in 1998, but subsequently it seems Huang has been publishing his work in his own journal *Advances in Adaptive Data Analysis*. If you go to his [research website](http://rcada.ncu.edu.tw/research1.htm) you can find (at the bottom) links to the full text of every article published in AADA.

[Here is some R code](https://gist.github.com/1536557) and data demonstrating running CEEMD in parallel in R.

Comment: Any chance of matlab implementation of CEEMD?

Comment: Nope, sorry; I'm pretty strongly opposed to the use of non-FOSS scientific computing.